# Can you get bank account number from card payment in stripe?

Tags: authentication, stripe-payments, gateway

I am looking for a payment gate for ex. stripe, where we would do micro payment for instant authentication. That means we charge a customer a minimal amount and when the transaction gets processed, we get the information about his bank account.

Open banking authentication would be an opinion but our country regulations do not allow authentication without actual payment.

So the solution is not micro-depostit as that is not instant, taxes a day or two, but a micro payment would work.

If you have any suggestions please leave them here. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why do you care about the customer's bank account number?

Answer (score -1):

With Stripe you have two options for this:

- Create a [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents) to collect a payment method that you can charge later
- Or use a [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) for a small amount ([$0.50 minimum](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts)) and save the payment method with [`setup_future_usage`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) to be able to reuse it later

The payment method could be a card, a bank, etc. You can see all supported payment method [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/overview).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does this resolve the requirement "get the information about his bank account"?